# Pick With Optional Keys

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, is it possible to have a [`Pick`-style](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktk) utility type in which keys can be specified which may or may not be available on the picked object type? For example:

```
interface Alpha
{
    a: boolean;
    b: boolean;
}

type Picked = OptionalPick<Alpha, 'a' | 'c'>; // { a: boolean }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is possible, we can define the second parameter `K` as just extending `PropertyKey` and then use `Extarct` to extract from `keyof T` any properties that are in the union `K`:

```
interface Alpha
{
    a: boolean;
    b: boolean;
}

type OptionalPick<T, K extends PropertyKey> = Pick<T, Extract<keyof T, K>>
type Picked = OptionalPick<Alpha, 'a' | 'c'>;
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIBsAOALOAoAbz2ROTgC5kAjAexvQjhAG5jSrLb7GW8BfPHjABPTCgDymMMBog46AArAEAawA8AFQA0yANLIIAD0ggAJgGdkCqDTFQRuiMIB8yALxXl67cgCixqEQwNRUnGhhkH11nZyFRFCVVCFN3ZElpWXlE9QwcOB0AcjgC5AAfZAKEAudmZCA)